# sfp+ switch for linux cluster

Tags: linux, switch, cluster-computing

I would like to build a linux computing cluster (multiple identical PCs connected via high speed networking so that they behave, for scientific calculations, like a single big "PC", with almost the entire computing power of the combined PCs, summed up). I would like to go from the start with SFP+ but I have no idea what specs should such switch meet and if any of those bellow are ok for this task:

1. Switch Mikrotik CRS317-1G-16S+RM, 16 x 10G SFP+
2. Switch Quanta LB6M 24x10Gbps
3. Switch TP-Link TL-SX3016F, 320 Gbps, 16 x SFP+

Now, I know there are better alternatives, but buying from ebay/amazon is not the route, for the moment (I have no idea how much the international/custom taxes will be and the postal service, from my country, has the bad habit of loosing packages).

1. Would any of these work for me?
2. Which one of the above you would recommend? And why?
3. Which one has the ability to transfer as much data as possible, but also being configurable from Linux?

TA
R

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about question 3. If a switch is configurable at all (managed) then it will have an administration webpage that any browser on any OS can access. And if it's a really unusual switch without an admin webpage it might still have Telnet or SSH access, which are both possible to work with on any OS.

Comment: thank you @Romen; unfortunately, my main concerns, on question 3, are about the amount of data transfered; I realize now, that most probably every switch in the world has one way of configuring things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Would any of these work for me?

The CRS317-1G-16S+RM and TL-SX3016F definitely will, and they both have good support.

> 2. Which one of the above you would recommend? And why?

I use the CRS317-1G-16S+RM with a number of 10G SFP+'s. I'm very happy. Well other than Mikrotik's command line interface is so much more difficult to understand than Cisco's. I've never tried the TP-Link cli.

I'd go Mikrotik over TP-Link due to cost.

> 3. Which one has the ability to transfer as much data as possible, but
>    also being configurable from Linux?

The Mikrotik wins by a hair on data, but those values are best case scenario. You wouldn't know which is best in your environment unless you tried both. Even then, you likely couldn't notice without precise measurement.

```
Mikrotik 239.5833 Mpps
TP-LINK 238.08 Mpps
```

Linux is simple, both support ssh connections to management.